# After checking the database is not connected to it

Tags: python, postgresql, heroku

I have connect to postgreql which write in documentation Heroku:

```
import dj_database_url
import os
import psycopg2


DATABASE_URL = os.environ['DATABASE_URL']
conn = psycopg2.connect(DATABASE_URL, sslmode='require')
DATABASE_URL['default'] = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=600, ssl_require=True)
```

And I have connect in code:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(
    database = data.database,
    user = data.user,
    password = data.password,
    host = data.host,
    port = data.port,
    sslmode = 'require'
)
cursor = conn.cursor()
```

They did some check of my database and after they finished at me nothing works and cannot be connected to a DB.
I get error:

```
2021-07-07T18:21:39.307157+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-07-07T18:21:39.307173+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/main.py", line 23, in <module>
2021-07-07T18:21:39.308848+00:00 app[worker.1]: conn = psycopg2.connect(
2021-07-07T18:21:39.308891+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
2021-07-07T18:21:39.309172+00:00 app[worker.1]: conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
2021-07-07T18:21:39.309299+00:00 app[worker.1]: psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "cozqztdivphuut"
```

All information about password, user, database ect. input correctly.
Help please, because I can't understand this^^

Comment: Write in heroku support I can't, because I user free plan.

Comment: Before that I worked without `sslmode = 'require'`, second code